# How to use pandas in google cloud data flow?

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Are there any methods to use pandas, numpy for doing transformations in google cloud data flow?

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-announces-cloud-dataflow-with-python-support
In the above link it says having support for numpy, scipy and pandas, But there are no examples available

Comment: Could you solve it  Eila ??

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow or Beam do not currently have transforms that use Numpy or Pandas. Nonetheless, you must be able to use them without much trouble.

If you give more info about your use case, we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I am using pandas to generate dataframe from data that is available on my GCS. However, I am not able to write the data to the gs:// as a text file. I am using the following pipline: with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
   (p 
    | 'Read-blobs' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://archs4/human_matrix.h5')
    | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://archs4/') 
   )
could you please advice? many thanks, Eila